# Show ambiguous name in view fetched through DB Builder in Laravel

Tags: laravel, view, query-builder

I am fetching data from three tables in which two tables (departmentdata and cities) have same field `name`. So when i show name field in my view then it display the value of name field at last occurrence of the result set.

```
//Controller source code
$leads = DB::table('leaddata')
->join('departmentdata', 'departmentdata.id', '=', 'leaddata.department')
->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'leaddata.citydata')
->get();

// View source code
<?php foreach ($leads as $lead) {
?>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    {{ $lead->name }}
<span>
<?php } ?>
```

How would i pick department name and city name separately to display in the view?

Comment: You can add to your query builder:

->select(departmentdata.name as dep_name)
->select(cities.name as city_name)

Comment: Sidenote, why are you using `<?php` and `{{ }}` in the same file? `.blade.php` is a templating engine and gives you the ability to run a `foreach` via `@foreach($leads as $lead) {{ $lead->name }} @endforeach`. Also, have you looked at Models and Relationships? You'd be able to do something like `$leads = Lead::with(['city', 'department'])->get()`, then `$lead->city->name` and `$lead->department->name`. If you're using Laravel, leverage everything it has to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliases:

```
$leads = DB::table('leaddata')
->select('departmentdata.name AS department', 'cities.name AS city')
->join('departmentdata', 'departmentdata.id', '=', 'leaddata.department')
->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'leaddata.citydata')
->get();
```

so you can:

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    {{$lead->department}} {{ $lead->city}} 
<span>
```